# Эмулятор для apple ipad mini

Tags: вёрстка, ipad, эмулятор

Я сделал адаптивность для сайта на Chrome 1024px и там всё выглядит хорошо. Но клиент проверил на Apple iPad mini и сказал что у него всё криво. Кто нибудь знает хороший эмулятор для Windows 10?

Comment: зачем эмуляторы если есть browserstack. Хотя я столкнулся как-то с такой бедой с flex, когда шеф проверил со старенькой iOS6.

Comment: Экран айпада мини 4 - 2048х1536px.

Comment: @Эникейщик, но сайт об этом не в курсе.

Answer (score 1):

- Для первичной проверки можно воспользоваться [Device Mode в Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3).
  Чтобы включить режим эмулятора нажмите `[Ctrl + Shift + M]` и
  выберите устройство, которое вы хотите эмулировать.
- Так же есть сервисы, которые имитируют стационарные и мобильные устройства для тестирования сайтов, например [Browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com) или [Responsinator](http://www.responsinator.com)

Answer (score 1):

Есть множество удобных сервисов для проверки на разных устройствах и браузерах.

Например:

- https://www.browserstack.com/
- http://quirktools.com/screenfly/
- https://www.browserling.com/

Safari на ios использует немного другой движок рендера сайтов, поэтому бывают маленькие промахи.